# How do I limit the results to 20?

Tags: powershell

Need to the limit the results of this to the first 20.

Is there another way I can loop this to get 20 results at a time?

```
$Array = @()
#Fill $Array with Data
$List = $Array | ForEach-Object {"$_`n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would limit ther returned results *prior* to the looping construct. My example uses the names of service objects, but I needed something to use...

```
$TOlist = (Get-Service).Name
$TOlist | Select-Object -First 20 | ForEach-Object {
    $_
}
```

You'll need to use at least two lines here. As far as I'm aware, you can't both assign your $TOlist variable *and* start sending each value down the pipeline.